# How can I use jQuery to travel between <section> tags using the up and down arrow keys?

Tags: jquery

I am in the process of designing a one-page website design and would like the user to be able to navigate between  tags using the up and down arrow key, I presume this would use jQuery, how would I do this?

Comment: What does it mean to 'travel' between tags?

Comment: slide, move, go up, go down :3

Comment: Not the kind of reply to actually get an answer with; just sayin'

Comment: Sorry, To be honest I wasn't to sure how else I could phrase it. I just want to be able to use the arrow keys (up and down) to slide to certain parts of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can attach handlers to click on the appropriate section with each key press (assuming you have a way to determine the current section); jQuery makes this pretty straightforward.  As for how to respond to such a click: with NO code provided, you're on your own.